# How do I set column values to null where they are 'null' in TSQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, null, data-cleaning

I've tried the following:

```
select 'update dbo.tableName set ' + sys.columns + ' = null where ' + sys.columns + ' = 'NULL'' from dbo.tableName
```

I imported a lot of excel data into ssms and the null values are actually varchars.

Comment: Is this something you want to run on all your tables or just a single table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you have multiple columns that have `'NULL'` as a string literal in multiple different rows in the same table, you better so something like this:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Col1 = NULLIF(Col1, 'NULL'),
    Col2 = NULLIF(Col2, 'NULL'),
    Col3 = NULLIF(Col3, 'NULL')
WHERE 'NULL' IN(Col1, Col2, Col3)
```

The `NULLIF` function will return `NULL` if both of it's arguments are the same, or the first argument otherwise.

If you want to do that dynamically for multiple tables, you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT  @SQL += 'UPDATE '+ TABLE_NAME + -- Update clause
        STUFF( -- Set clause start
        (
            SELECT ',' + COLUMN_NAME +  '= NULLIF('+ COLUMN_NAME +', ''NULL'')'
            FROM Information_schema.Columns C
            WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
            FOR XML PATH('')    
        ), 1, 1, ' SET ') + -- Set clause end
        ' WHERE ''NULL'' IN(' + -- Where clause start
        STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ','+ COLUMN_NAME
            FROM Information_schema.Columns C
            WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
            FOR XML PATH('')    
        ),1, 1, '')+ ');' -- Where clause end
FROM Information_schema.Tables T;

EXEC(@SQL);
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/AIAU64397)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NULLIF (ColA, 'NULL') AS ColA
```

Comment: The NULLIF() function creates NULL values under certain conditions.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.